# NodeJS undefined var gets error

Tags: node.js

I hope this is a quite easy question but I couldn't understand why is not working.

My problem, I access to a variable that could be not defined.

This is the function:

```
  app.get('/loc', function (req, res) {

    if (typeof req.user.userId === 'undefined'){
        redirect('/');
    } else {
        var userId = req.user.userId;
        Loc.getP([userId], function(promos) {
           res.render('local/index', {
            title: 'Local'
          });   
        });
    }
  });
```

The problem is at the line that I'm checking if the var is undefined. If not, I just want to redirect to other url. If it's defined, render data of the user. Quite simple, but always I try to access req.user.userId I get the following:

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
```

I tried everything I found at internet, but I think in JS it has to work...

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that req.user is available ? For sure, you have to check if req.user is not undefined first :)

Comment: As I thought, quite easy ;) but at this time at night need a little help. thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should check first if req.user is defined then do your userID check.

```
if (req.user && typeof req.user.userId === 'undefined'){
```

alternately you can test it like this:

```
if (typeof req.user === 'undefined' && typeof req.user.userId === 'undefined'){
```

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter:

```
if (!(req.user || {}).userId){
```

It's also worth mentioning that lodash has a function for this:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get

Comment: Cool, I liked this one!

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS has a Util Class which have the [isNullOrUndefined()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isnullorundefined_object) method to check if a variable is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: looks like this is deprecated. any alternative?

Comment: This library https://validatejs.org have a very big list of useful methods under https://validatejs.org/#utilities

Answer (score 0):

following code is more simple :

```
if (!req.user || !req.user.userId){ // redirect
```

Comment: In this case this would probably be okay, but if you might expect the userId to be 0 or an empty string, it would evaluate as false even though it really does have a value. See Truth-y and False-y slides in this presentation: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/Publications/javascriptsurprises.pdf